# Insert content before first iteration of foreach loop

Tags: php, foreach, html-lists

I have a simple php foreach loop, it echo's out a simple list, ex:

```
<ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

How can I insert a miscellaneous list item before the first item of the foreach loop. Ex:

```
<ul>
    <li>Random li content inserted</li>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post your array or php code?

Comment: Add it to the start of the array before loop with http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unshift.php I'm on my phone, no sample code.

Comment: Numerous ways. Show us what you are doing currently if you want some solutions

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Where's the problem? Just output it before your loop.

```
<ul>
    <li>Random li content inserted</li>
    <?php foreach($items as $item) { ?>
      <li><?php echo htmlspecialchars($item); ?></li>
    <?php } ?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

plz try like this..

```
    <ul>
        <li>Random li content inserted</li>

         <?php 
            //foreach to display <li>
         ?>
    </ul>
```